# Convert PDF to JPG2000 file(s)

Tags: java, pdfbox, javax.imageio, image-conversion

I recently started working on this project where I need to convert a PDF File into a JPEG2000 file(s) - 1 jp2 file per page -.

The goal was to replace a previous pdf to jpeg converter method we had, in order to reduce the size of the  output file(s).

Based on a code I found on the internet, I made the pdftojpeg2000 converter method below, and I've been changing the **setEncodingRate** parameter value and comparing the results.

I managed to get smaller jpeg2000 output files, but the quality is very poor, compared to the Jpeg ones, specially for colored text or images.

Here is what my orginal pdf file looks like:

[image]

When I set **setEncodingRate** to 0.8 it looks like this:

[image]

My output file size is 850Ko, which is even bigger than the Jpeg (around 600Ko) ones, and lower quality.

At 0.1 **setEncodingRate**, the file size is considerably small, 111 Ko, but basically unreadable.

[image]

So basically what I'm trying to get here is smaller output files ( <600K ) with a better quality, And I'm wondering if it is feasible with the Jpeg2000 format.

```
public class ImageConverter {

 public void compressor(String inputFile, String outputFile) throws IOException {
        J2KImageWriteParam iwp = new J2KImageWriteParam();
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File (inputFile), MemoryUsageSetting.setupMixed(10485760L));
        PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
        int nbPages = document.getNumberOfPages();
        int pageCounter = 0;
        BufferedImage image;
        for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
            if (page.hasContents()) {
                image = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageCounter, 300, ImageType.RGB);


                if (image == null) 
                {
                    System.out.println("If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream");
                }

                Iterator writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("JPEG2000");
                String name = null;
                ImageWriter writer = null;
                while (name != "com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KImageWriter") {
                    writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();
                    name = writer.getClass().getName();
                    System.out.println(name);
                }
                File f = new File(outputFile+"_"+pageCounter+".jp2");
                long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
                ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(f);
                writer.setOutput(ios);
                J2KImageWriteParam param = (J2KImageWriteParam) writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
                IIOImage ioimage = new IIOImage(image, null, null);

                param.setSOP(true);
                param.setWriteCodeStreamOnly(true);
                param.setProgressionType("layer");
                param.setLossless(true);
                param.setCompressionMode(J2KImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
                param.setCompressionType("JPEG2000");
                param.setCompressionQuality(0.01f);
                param.setEncodingRate(1.01);
                param.setFilter(J2KImageWriteParam.FILTER_53 );                                 
                writer.write(null, ioimage, param);
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - s);
                writer.dispose();
                ios.flush();
                ios.close();
                image.flush();

                pageCounter++;
            }
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        String input = "E:/IMGTEST/mail-DOC0002.pdf";
        String output = "E:/IMGTEST/mail-DOC0002/docamail-DOC0002-";
        ImageConverter imgcv = new ImageConverter();
        try {
            imgcv.compressor(input, output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: PNG format will typically produce smaller image sizes than JPEG  for text. PNG is also a 100% correct representation of the original source, as opposed to JPEG.

Comment: It seems to me that you have some color space issue here as well. Either the images aren't properly converted to RGB by the PDF renderer, or perhaps the result images contain alpha and the JPEG2000 reader/writer will misinterpret the 4 components as CMYK. Second, I'm not sure if specifying lossless *and* a compression quality or encoding rate makes sense... Finally: Why does it have to be JPEG2000?